# Как задавать начальные и конечные значения для круглых прогресс баров?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progress-bar

В данный момент мой progress bar заполняется от процента приходящего в компонент. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы начальная точка прогресса изменялась в зависимости от startTime, а конечная от endTime. Как это можно реализовать?

```
<template>
  <div class="progress-circle__container">
    <span class="progress-circle__percent">{{ percentage }}</span>

   <svg class="stat-circle" viewBox="1.6 1.6 16.8 16.8">
    <circle class="bg" cx="10" cy="10" r="6"/>
    <circle class="progress" cx="10" cy="10" r="6" :style="{strokeDashoffset: circle}" :data-percentage="percentage"/>

   </svg>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'stat-circle',
    data() {
     return {
        shift: {
         startTime: '8:00',
         endTime: '18:00'
        }
     }
    },
    props: {
      percentage: {
        type: Number
      }
    },
    computed: {
      circle() {
        return -51 -((51 / 100) * this.percentage);
      }
    }
   }
 </script>
<style lang="scss">
  .progress-circle {

    &__container{
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 80px;
      max-height: 80px;

      position: relative;
    }

    &__percent {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

      font-size: 28px;

      &::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;

        background-color: #2C3144;
        border-radius: 100px;
        z-index: -1;
      }


    }
  }

  .stat-circle {
    circle.bg {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #2C3144;
      stroke-width: 1;
    }
    circle.progress {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #10B15A;
      stroke-width: 1.4;
      stroke-dasharray: 51 51;
      stroke-dashoffset: -51;
      stroke-linecap: round;
    }
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может кому пригодится, решил задачу данным способом

```
    <template>
  <div class="progress-circle__container">
    <span class="progress-circle__inner">{{ code }}</span>

    <svg class="stat-circle"  width="120" height="120">
      <circle class="stat-circle__bg" cx="60" cy="60" r="44"/>
      <circle
        class="stat-circle__progress stat-circle__progress--daily"
        v-bind:style='{
          strokeDasharray: strokeDasharray,
          strokeDashoffset: dailyProgress.strokeDashoffset,
          transform: dailyProgress.rotate,
          stroke: dailyProgress.color
        }'
        cx="60"
        cy="60"
        r="44"/>
      <circle
        class="stat-circle__progress stat-circle__progress--night"
        v-bind:style='{
          strokeDasharray: strokeDasharray,
          strokeDashoffset: nightProgress.strokeDashoffset,
          transform: nightProgress.rotate,
          stroke: nightProgress.color
        }'
        cx="60"
        cy="60"
        r="44"/>
      <circle class="stat-circle__start-point" r="10" cx="20" cy="20"/>
    </svg>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'stat-circle',
  data() {
    return {
      dailyProgress: {
        rotate: '',
        strokeDasharray: '',
        strokeDashoffset: '',
        color: ''
      },
      nightProgress: {
        rotate: '',
        strokeDasharray: '',
        strokeDashoffset: '',
        color: ''
      },
      circumference: '',
      dailyColor: '#10B15A',
      nightColor: '#4F3EC8',
      nightStart: 23,
      nightEnd: 6,
    }
  },
  props: {
    startTime: {
      type: Number
    },
    endTime: {
      type: Number
    },
    code: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setAllProgress() {
      if((this.startTime > this.nightStart && this.startTime < this.nightEnd) ||
        (this.endTime > this.nightStart && this.endTime < this.nightEnd) ||
        (this.startTime < this.nightStart && this.endTime > this.nightEnd && this.endTime < 12)) {
        this.setProgress(this.getPercentTime, this.getFirstPercent, this.dailyProgress, this.dailyColor);
        this.setProgress(this.getPercentTimeNight, this.getFirstPercentNight, this.nightProgress, this.nightColor);
      } else {
        this.setProgress(this.getPercentTime, this.getFirstPercent, this.dailyProgress, this.dailyColor);
      }
    },
    getCircumference() {
      const circle = document.querySelector('.stat-circle__bg');
      const radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;

      this.circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius
    },

    setProgress(percentTime, firstPercent, progressBar, color) {
      const offset = this.circumference - percentTime / 100 * this.circumference;
      const rotate = 360 * firstPercent - 90;

      progressBar.strokeDasharray = `${this.circumference} ${this.circumference}`;
      progressBar.rotate = `rotate(${rotate}deg)`;
      progressBar.strokeDashoffset = offset;
      progressBar.color = color;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    strokeDasharray() {
      return `${this.circumference} ${this.circumference}`
    },

    getPercentTime() {
      return ((this.endTime - this.startTime) / 12) * 100
    },

    getPercentTimeNight() {
      if (this.endTime <= 6) {
        return ((this.endTime - this.nightStart) / 12) * 100
      } else {
        return ((this.nightEnd - this.nightStart) / 12) * 100
      }
    },

    getFirstPercent() {
      return this.startTime / 12
    },

    getFirstPercentNight() {
      return this.nightStart / 12
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getCircumference();
    this.setAllProgress();
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .progress-circle {

    &__container{
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 120px;
      max-height: 120px;

      position: relative;
    }

    &__inner {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

      font-size: 28px;

      &::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;

        background-color: #2C3144;
        border-radius: 100px;
        z-index: -1;
      }


    }
  }

  .stat-circle {
    position: relative;

    &__bg {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #2C3144;
      stroke-width: 8;
    }

    &__start-point {
      fill: green;
      transform-origin: center;
    }

    &__progress {
      fill: none;

      stroke-width: 8.2;
      stroke-linecap: round;

      transform-origin: center;
      transform: rotate(-90deg);

      &--night {
        stroke-width: 8.8;
      }

    }
  }

</style>
```